# Cannot deploy the JDBC driver

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, jdbc

I have this app that Inherited from another developer and I don't know much about java.  This app was working just fine a few minutes ago, but now I get the following error:

> Cannot deploy the JDBC driver to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41\lib\jtds-1.2.jar.
>   Check whether you have write access rights to the C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41\lib folder.

These are the additional errors  I got from the apache log:

> Jul 30, 2014 4:10:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   tag 'select', field 'list', name 'country': The requested list key 'util.countries' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.fieldError(Component.java:237)
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:358)
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.ListUIBean.evaluateExtraParams(ListUIBean.java:80)
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.Select.evaluateExtraParams(Select.java:105)
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:856)
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:510)
>       at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
>       at org.apache.jsp.user.register_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fselect_005f0(register_jsp.java:938)
>       at org.apache.jsp.user.register_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f1(register_jsp.java:577)
>       at org.apache.jsp.user.register_jsp._jspService(register_jsp.java:210)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:154)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:362)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:266)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
>       at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at dfqeas.interceptors.AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:55)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

This error comes up when  I run the project. I have no idea what this error means, I am totally new to Java(day 1). Please assist.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? Windows won't let you overwrite files that are open, and it could be that something still has that jar open.

Comment: Does the `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41\lib` directory exist? Is this where the tomcat is installed?

Comment: @chrylis i rebooted windows twice, but still no luck.

Comment: @dimoniy yes, that directory exists

Comment: check in the task manager if you have an apache windows process running, if yes stop it and try again

Comment: @fmodos still no luck

Comment: @user2995165 ok, but is the "cannot deploy jdbc driver" error still happening?

Comment: @fmodos I think I may have an idea of what the issue may be. the app is running on port 8084, but tomcat is running on port 8080. How do I go about changing the port number ?

Comment: @user2995165 the app run under tomcat port, it is not possible to start an app with a different port

Comment: @fmodos the reason I think it runs on a different port is because of this `start?path=/online
OK - Started application at context path /online
run-deploy:
Browsing: http://localhost:8084/online`. thats from nedbeans console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58384/discussion-between-user2995165-and-fmodos).

Comment: You need Administrator privileges, and - if UAC is enabled - administrator elevation to write in Program files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most probably because of the following line

> Check whether you have write access rights to the C:\Program
>   Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41\lib

Since your tomcat is installed to the above path and most of the user's don't have write access to the `C:\Program Files\..` folder.

You can download a zip/tgz [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) and then copy the jdbc jar to its lib and try to use it.

This may solve your issue !